# Postman GET request works but not Ajax CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I am trying to make an AJAX request to get information of a restAPI.

If I test it with POSTMAN, it works and with Putty too with this code selecting RAW, but not with AJAX due to CORS issues.

This is the code that works on Putty (it returns JSON data):

```
GET /api/slot/0/io/do HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: 172.25.0.208\r\n
Content-Type: application/json\r\n
Accept: vdn.dac.v1\r\n
\r\n
```

This is the jQuery AJAX code:

```
//Build GET Request URL
var url = "//" + ipDevice + "/api/slot/" + slot + "/io/do";
jQuery.support.cors = true;
//GET Request with HTTP header info
$.ajax({
    "url": url,
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "vdn.dac.v1",
        "Content-type": "application/json"
    },
    "success": function (response) {
        getPowerStatusSuccess(response);
    },
    "error": function (response) {
        getPowerStatusFail(response);
    }
});
```

The error I got on browser console (Firefox) is:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Answer (score 1):

Your api needs to return a cors header ~allow-origin set to * or a whitelist of domains.

`access-control-allow-origin: *`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it isn’t my API, so I cannot add this header.